# How do I test cover simple JSON creation in a trigger?

Tags: unit-test, json, code-coverage

I have an contact after trigger which collects data from Contact, add some personal, authentication pairs, and updates a 3rd party system.

While the insertion of account/contact in the test class is easy, I don't understand how do I test cover the creation of the json object.

Since the data it uses is hard coded.

These lines did (do?) not pass the test coverage:

[image]

The class:

> trigger trgSF2NSContact on Contact (after update, after insert) {

```
String jsonData;

// Create a list of integers to write to the JSON string.
List<Id> idlist = new List<Id>();

for(Contact con : Trigger.new) {

    // Only update contacts for accounts that are in NS

    Account myAcct = [SELECT Id, Total_Closed_Opptys__c, NS_External_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :con.AccountId ];
    if (myAcct.Total_Closed_Opptys__c == 0)
    {
        system.debug('Account not in NS');
        system.debug('                S H O U L D     R E T U R N !!!!');
        return;
    }

    system.debug('    Account is in Netsuite !!!!!!');

    JSONGenerator jsGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

    system.debug('json debug' + json.serialize(con));
    jsGen.writeStartObject();

    jsGen.writeStringField('mappingtype', 'Contact_Mapping');
    jsGen.writeStringField('recordtype', 'Contact');
    jsGen.writeStringField('Name', con.LastName);
    if (con.FirstName != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('FirstName', con.FirstName);
    jsGen.writeStringField('CurrencyIsoCode', con.CurrencyIsoCode);
    idlist.add(con.Id);
    jsGen.writeStringField('Id', con.Id);
    jsGen.writeStringField('SF_Account_id', myAcct.Id);

    if (con.Phone != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Phone', con.Phone);
    if (con.Email != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Email', con.Email);
    if (con.Title != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Title', con.Title);
    if (con.Fax != NULL) jsGen.writeStringField('Fax', con.Fax);

    jsGen.writeEndObject();

    jsonData = jsGen.getAsString();
    system.debug('jsonData DATA SENT TO NS !!!!! \n : ' + jsonData);
}

SF2NSHandleContact.handleContact(idlist, jsonData);
}
```

Test class :

```
> @isTest
public class trgSF2NSContactTest{
static testMethod void insertNewUser() {

    Account acctTest = new Account();
    accttest.Name = 'test account';
    acctTest.NS_External_ID__c =  '223344';
    accttest.BillingCountry = 'Israel';

    insert accttest;

    Contact contactToCreate = new Contact();
    contactToCreate.LastName = 'last';
    contactToCreate.FirstName = 'first';
    contactToCreate.CurrencyIsoCode= 'USD';
    contactToCreate.Phone = '0545558335';
    contactToCreate.Email = 'test@gmail.com';
    contactToCreate.Title = 'CIO';
    contactToCreate.Fax = '039888979'; 
    contactToCreate.MailingCountry = 'Israel'; 
    contacttocreate.AccountId = accttest.Id;


    insert ContactToCreate;
    }
}
```

So assuming the JSON is within a class, how do I test it?

Comment: Do you mean functional testing or in regards to code coverage ?

Comment: test coverage (adding test class)

Comment: Off topic: you have a query into a loop, warn.
On Topic: are you sure that is not returning (breaking the trigger) when evaluate `if (myAcct.Total_Closed_Opptys__c == 0)`?

Comment: Yes, can you tell us a bit about Total_Closed_Opptys__c - is it a formula, rollup, integer? I believe your test class is probably not getting past the IF that Martin mentioned.

Comment: totally correct: Total_closed_opptys is a roll up. I inserted a closed won oppty, and I get now 100% coverage. Missed that small part. @MartinBorthiry feel free to post as answer

Comment: @MartinBorthiry I am an old guy, doing new code, using old guy's methods of coding ^^ - can't be bother with bulkifying code...

Comment: Came on @Saariko you are a Triathlete! you could code anything ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Off topic**: you have a query into a loop, warn.

**On Topic**: are you sure that is not returning (breaking the trigger) when evaluates `if (myAcct.Total_Closed_Opptys__c == 0)`?

If `Total_Closed_Opptys__c` is a roll up, your json code will not be run.

In addition, your code in a **bulk-safe** way should look like this:

```
//.... same prev code here...
// prepare the list of account ids
Id[] accountIds = new Id[]{};
for(Contact con : Trigger.new) {
   accountIds.add(con.accountId);
}
// now you have to create an account map
map<id, Account> accounts = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Total_Closed_Opptys__c, NS_External_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id in :accountIds ]);



for(Contact con : Trigger.new) {

    // Only update contacts for accounts that are in NS
    // here you avoid the query by using the map.
    Account myAcct = accounts.get(con. AccountId);
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was accepted, it might helped the OP with other issues but not with the mentioned issue - how to cover JsonGenerator code?